# Yelp Like Adjective Rating System

Tags: user-behavior, voting, ratings

I am building a website that has users list their outdoor adventures (skydiving, surfing, base jumping, etc) and the other people can comment on them.

I want to have a rating system like Yelp which has "Useful, Funny, or Cool" but with different adjectives.  I have thought of a few such as Daring, Adventurous, and Unique but I wanted to get some feedback on what a few other good adjectives would be.

Also does anyone have experience with other such systems or advice for better systems?  Primarily I just want the user to have somewhat more descriptive voting options than u and down or 1 though 5.

Answer (score 1):

As for collecting the adjectives, I think the enthusiasts of those activities (the domain experts) would be a good source.

("mellow", "nectar", "hectic", "gnarly"?  I'm a little out of touch.)